# Jest how to modify the global object value for each unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm writing unit tests that require the window.location.href to be defined
The first unit test is created as follows

```
  describe('myMethod()', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      global.window = Object.create(window);
      Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
        configurable: true,
        value: {
          href: 'http://localhost:7777/mainPoint?param=val1',
        },
      });
    });

    it('should call with val1', () => {
      myMethod();
      expect(myService.detectURLCall).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://localhost:7777/mainPoint?param=val1'); // passes
    });

  describe('mySecondMethod()', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      global.window = Object.create(window);
      Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
        configurable: true,
        value: {
          href: 'http://localhost:7777/mainPoint?param=val2',
        },
      });
    });

    it('should call with val2', () => {
      myMethod();
      expect(myService.detectURLCall).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://localhost:7777/mainPoint?param=val2'); // fails, the received call was ending with =val1
    })
```

I know that the jest unit tests run in parallel, I tried doing clearMocks() in an afterEach() inside myMethod() test suite but it did not help and my second test suit still detects what we defined in the first one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following looks to be a good solution for your issue:

https://github.com/simon360/jest-environment-jsdom-global 
(built on top of jest's built-in jest-environment-jsdom, and has a good readme that directly relates)

This ensures that you have one defined environment per file, which would definitely be the root issue as you said.

Comment: I haven't needed it for that, but based on what it's doing, I don't see why not.  Give it a shot and let me know if you get stuck.  One note with localStorage that's easy to forget, make sure you reset it in the beforeEach if you have multiple tests in the file.